# Check if dynamic link library is outdated

Tags: c++, c, dll, module

Is there a reliable way to check if a dll is outdated? For example, I some build systems store a checksum of the module's code files and then stores in in a file.

Is there a way to store this sort of checksum inside the dll metadata so that you don't have to keep an extra file around?

Comment: Doesn't seem worth the trouble to me.  Most build systems I'm familiar with rely on timestamps, and if ever you're not confident, it's usually not a big deal to perform a clean build (since you seem to be supposing that the sources are in fact at hand).  I know Scons performs checksumming -- and that can slow it considerably -- but that's more about determining during a build which sources (if any) have changed, not about comparing the built object to its sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways you could store this information inside your dll, but the simplest (to me) would be to have your build system generate a header file with a `const char[] checksum = "whatever_the_checksum_is";` that you then `#include` in your dll code.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not sufficient to store a version number within the DLL to check against with the build system?
Or just take a version number as a part of the DLL filename where you can check this. This is a standard way under Linux
with shared libs (.so).